# how can i create a button like bookmark with star image along with listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

i want to create a button or check box with an image along with listview.I have a list of items  which are retrieved from the databse using jquery for each item there should be an image button,the image could be star,i want to implement a concept like bookmark..
i want to add in this list,how can i do this??

```
var htmlStr = '<li><a><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Word']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+row['Type_Of_Word']+'</p></a></li>';
```

Comment: try [jquery-ui button with icons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons)

Comment: it is ok..but i want to make a custom image..like i have to put my ow icon with my listview..

Comment: just create new ui-icon-mystar in css

Comment: ok got an idea,so can i write like this?? **bold** `<button id="demo"></button>

 $(function() {
  $( ".demo button:first" ).button({
            icons: {
   background-image:url('star.png');
               
            },
            text: false
        })
  
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your own icon using css:

```
.ui-state-default  .ui-icon-mystar {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Full_Star_Red.svg/64px-Full_Star_Red.svg.png); 
   background-size: 100%;
    
}​
```

in javascript:

```
$('#starbutton').button({icons: {primary:'ui-icon-mystar'}});​
```

in html:

```
<a href="#" id="starbutton">Bookmark</a>​
```

[working sample:](http://jsfiddle.net/dqpLN/)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the css and jquery code snippet

```
    .star {
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url('http://localhost/technicalkeeda/images/star-off.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        display: block;  
        height:16px;
        width:16px;
        float:left;
    }   

    .favorited {
         text-indent: -5000px;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url('http://localhost/technicalkeeda/images/star-on.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;   
        height:16px;
        width:16px;
        float:left;
    }



$(document).ready(function(){   
     $('.star,.favorited').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');             
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            var flag  = (className=='star') ? 'Y':'N';
            var $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "yoururl",
                    cache: false,               
                    data:{'bookmarkId': id,'flag':flag},
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response=='true'){                               
                            $this.toggleClass("favorited");
                        }   
                    },
                    error: function(){                      
                        alert('Error while request..');
                    }
                 });
      });
});
```